# How to do a timediff or datediff query in CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I want to run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `foobar`
where
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,request_time,NOW()) < 15
```

I have tried:

```
$this->find('first',
                array('conditions' => 
                   array('username' => $v['User']['username']),
                   'TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,request_time,NOW()) < ' => 15));
```

Comment: you should state what cake version you are using. also: you should use virtual fields for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to place the SQL fragment inside of the `conditions` array, currently it's placed outside and thus it's being ignored.

```php
$this->find('first', array
(
    'conditions' => array
    (
        'username' => $v['User']['username'],
        // this is where it needs to go
        'TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, request_time, NOW()) < ' => 15
    )
    // this is where it was before
));
```

That will result in a query similar to this:

```sql
SELECT
    `Model`.`username`, ...
FROM
    `db`.`model` AS `Model`
WHERE
    `username` = 'whatever'
    AND
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, request_time, NOW()) < 15
LIMIT 1
```

By default CakePHP will include all fields in the `SELECT` statement.

Obviously if you want the query to use only the `TIMESTAMPDIFF` condition as in your example, then you have to drop `'username' => $v['User']['username']`.